# arduino nano + nrf2401 CRC_lenght=disable

Tags: arduino, radio-transmission

i have bought a arduino nano with a nrf2401 but the CRC_lenght is disable when i use the nf24/exemple/scanne

```
this is what i get
STATUS       = 0x00 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=0 TX_FULL=0
RX_ADDR_P0-1     = 0x0000000000 0x0000000000
RX_ADDR_P2-5     = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
TX_ADDR      = 0x0000000000
RX_PW_P0-6   = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
EN_AA        = 0x00
EN_RXADDR    = 0x00
RF_CH        = 0x00
RF_SETUP     = 0x00
CONFIG       = 0x00
DYNPD/FEATURE    = 0x00 0x00
Data Rate    = 1MBPS
Model        = nRF24L01
CRC Length   = Disabled
PA Power     = PA_MIN
000000000000000011111111111111112222222222222222333333333333333344444444444444445555555555555555666666666666666677777777777777
0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcd
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and i found on the web that normally it need to be like this

```
STATUS       = 0x0e RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=7 TX_FULL=0
RX_ADDR_P0-1     = 0xe7e7e7e7e7 0xc2c2c2c2c2
RX_ADDR_P2-5     = 0xc3 0xc4 0xc5 0xc6
TX_ADDR      = 0xe7e7e7e7e7
RX_PW_P0-6   = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
EN_AA        = 0x3f
EN_RXADDR    = 0x03
RF_CH        = 0x4c
RF_SETUP     = 0x07
CONFIG       = 0x0c
DYNPD/FEATURE    = 0x00 0x00
Data Rate    = 1MBPS
Model        = nRF24L01+
CRC Length   = 16 bits
PA Power     = PA_HIGH
```

why is the CRC Length and other things are not the same other things can be because of the brand but the most weird thing is hy CRC Length is disable instead off 16 bits

this is the cable settings

CE=pin7

CSN=pin8

SCK=pin13

MO=pin11

MI=pin12

of corse i have change this line RF24 radio(7,8); with the CE and CSN pin

Answer (score 0):

> "normally it need to be like this"

Why do you think that? Nothing needs to be like this unless you want to have the very same outcome.

NRF2401 has 144 configuration bits and they exist so you can configure them to your liking/needs.

As for all configurable things there are different configurations.

Yours looks like some default configuration as most values are 0 or disabled what I would expect when nothing has been configured yet.

Comment: i think that because i don't know why but when i follow exemple on youtube it doesn't work on off the two nrf24 doesn't send or doesn't receive

Comment: @superlearner probably becaue you did not configure your chip yet or is that part of the example and does not work as intended?

Comment: this is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57pdX6b0sfw i don't think it talks about it, but how can i do the configure of the chip. Thanks for helping

Comment: @superlearner read the chips datasheet/manual. there are Arduino libraries for that chip that provide functions for all configuration options. compare with other tutorials.

Comment: there was no chips datasheet when i bought it

Comment: there is a datasheet for every ship. how else would anyone know how to use it? they are all available by searching the web for the chip name

Comment: hie if the PA power is high or low it has difference but i thought that with this kit it would work with a power between 3V and 5V https://www.amazon.fr/WayinTop-Emetteur-R%C3%A9cepteur-Tutoriel-R%C3%A9gulateur/dp/B07ZCJPJ8B/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=nrf24+%2B+arduino+nano&qid=1587936794&sr=8-3 i'me sorry it's in frensh but you can see what componment i have. If never you have an nrf2401 can you send me what you get with scanner, please. Thanks for stilling hellping me even if i don't know a lot